# jQuery Code Organisation (Also tips)

Tags: jquery

I have started to use jQuery.. I am struggling to understand how the organise the code and how to use it properly. At the moment I am using code similar to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('all of the jquery goodness here');
  $('#div1').click(function(){
    /* some manipulation stuff here */
  })
})
```

Is there a better way of having loads of click handlers after the dom has loaded ?

Also is there some links to where I can get information regarding code layout in jquery ? I've been looking around source code but cannot find anything useful..

Thanks guys

[Edit]

Another quick question whilst I remember - Is it bad practice to use something similar to:

```
function clickedevent(){
    $('').toggle or other random jquery function
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "where I can layout code"?

Answer (score 1):

How I do it is something like this:

```
// Short notation for document ready
$(function(){
    // Bind the button to the method
    $(".button").click(methods.handlers.clickhandler1);
});

var methods = {
    handlers : {
        clickhandler1 : function(){
            alert("Y");
        }
    },
    method1 : function(){

    }
    // ETC
};
```

I sort it into a json object for some structure and dont do a .click(function(){}) next after next, because then you can't find what your actually binding on document ready, more overview.

If you wan't to learn more about jQuery structure and making your own plugins, read the following URL http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) to write more Object-Oriented javascript. While on that topic, an excellent read is [Douglas Crawford's 'Javascript: The Good Parts'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742). Here is an example of the module pattern with jQuery:

```
  window.MyCoolModule= (function(){
    var doCoolStuff = function(){
        alert("badumpumbishh")
    }
    var otherCoolStuff = function(){
        alert("someone..moved their..mouse.. all over me");
    }

    var superSecretPrivateFunction = function(){
        // come at me bro
    }

    return{
        somePublicFunction: function(){
            //hello, i can be called by other people
        },

        init: function(){
            $("#div1")
                    .bind("click", doCoolStuff)
                    .bind("mouseover", otherCoolStuff)

            $("#div2")
                .bind("click", superSecretPrivateFunction)
        }
    }
}())

$(function(){
    MyCoolModule.init()
})
```

Some points to note:

- Everything under "return" is public (it can be called by other
  objects) and everything above that is private (cannot be accessed
  outside this object)
- I lump all my bindings into one block of code '.bind("click",
  doCoolStuff)', so at a glance you can see all the DOM elements your
  module is listening to.
- I give the event handlers descriptive names rather than defining them
  inline '.bind("click", function(){}'.
- User 'bind("click", ...)' rather than '.click', even though they do
  the same thing. This is because jQuery also has a 'unbind' method
  which is useful, and I like having the mirrored reciprocal naming.
  But the bigger reason is that you can namespace functions. i.e you
  can do 'bind("click.customNamespace, ...)'. A reason to do this is
  that you can later do '.trigger("click.customNamespace") and it'll
  trigger only those namespaced events as opposed to all click events.
- You could do the $.ready check inside of init instead of outside -
  matter of coding style.

Answer (score 0):

Better than what? That's when you want to attach them.

You can move the click handler function itself into a named function rather than inlining it.

Sometimes you can refactor and use a function generator to create the click-handling function and reduce duplication of code.

Comment: So I should put the .click() handler function outside of the     $(document).ready() function ?

Comment: @broomgb Totally depends; you could, as in Niels' answer. Or have them as functions inside the DOM ready function. Keeping them from overwriting other functionality is the most important part.

Answer (score 0):

a very simplistic approach:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    assignSomeClicks();
    assignSomeOtherClicks();
});

function assignSomeClicks() {
    $('#div1').click(function(){
        ...
    });
}

function assignSomeOtherClicks() {
    ...
}
```

of course the purists will cry, and the java guys will die seeing that.

However, when you start to want to organise your JS code, you have basically 2 options. this one so that the style stay simple and consistant, or go full object approach.

these days, I use "modules" (plugins) with "init" function which handle handlers.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    fileExplorer.init();
    fileViewer.init();
    taskAssignation.init();
});
```

in antoher js file

```
var fileExplorer = new function () {
    // local stuff
    var thing;
    function buggify() {...};
    // public stuff
    this.init = function () {
       $('.fileExplorer').click(function () {...}); 
    }
}
```

Note that it requires some standards and assumptions, like class names and such.

Note too that here i use the syntax "new function" but you can use object too (`var fileExplorer = { init: function () {...}, ... }` or other methods (like `var fileExplorer = function () { return {init: function () {...}, ...}; }`). I like the "new Function" syntax one as it's the simplest, in my opinion, to have private and public stuff.

If you do jquery plugins, it's easy, you can bind your stuff inside the plugin itself.

Then you can start to use (function () {})(), but i don't understand the concept of closures fully enough yet to feel comfortable enough to use them.